# How are the imports implemented in different React libraries and how can I implement the same pattern in my own library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, material-ui, react-bootstrap

For example, the recommended way of importing in React Bootstrap is to go this way:

`import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'` instead of `import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';`

The reason is "Doing so pulls in only the specific components that you use, which can significantly reduce the amount of code you end up sending to the client."

source: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/

Same for React MUI components:

`import Button from '@mui/material/Button';`

source: https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/usage/

I want to implement something similar in my React components library, to limit the usage of code in the bundle, but I don't know how they implement this specific pattern. I have looked at their code base, but I don't quite understand.

Answer (score 1):

It might not be as complicated as you think. Let's say you write the following library:

```js
// your-library.js

const A = 22
const B = 33

export function getA () { return A }
export function getB () { return B }

export function APlusB () { return A + B }

// a lot of other stuff here
```

If some consumer of your library wants to make use of the `APlusB` function, they must do the following:

```js
// their-website.js
import { APlusB } from 'your-library'

const C = APlusB()
```

However, depending on how the code is bundled, they may or may not wind up with the entire `your-library` file in their web bundle. Modern bundling tools like [Webpack may provide tree shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/) to eliminate dead code, but this should be considered an additional optimization that the API consumer can opt into rather than a core behavior of the `import` spec.

To make your library more flexible, you can split up independent functions or chunks of functionality into their own files while still providing a full bundle for users who prefer that option. For example:

```js
// your-library/constants.js

export const A = 22
export const B = 33
```

```js
// your-library/aplusb.js
import { A, B } from 'constants'

export default function APlusB () { return A + B }
```

```js
// your-library/index.js

// instead of declaring everything in one file, export it from each module
export * from 'constants'
export { default as APlusB } from 'aplusb'
// more exports here
```

For distribution purposes you can package your library like so:

```js
your-library
|__aplusb.js
|__constants.js
|__index.js
```

You mentioned react-bootstrap and you can see this exact pattern in their file structure:

https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/tree/master/src

and you can see they aggregate and re-export modules in their index file here:

https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/master/src/index.tsx

Comment: Hey, thanks for the effort of answering with so many details.
Regarding the library example, I am in fact using a similar structure to yours.


src
|__ atoms
|____ button.jsx
|____ another-component.jsx
|____ index.js


In `index.js`, I'm exporting like so

export { Button } from './button'.
export { AnotherComponent } from './another-component'


Then, when I use this library in a project, I'm doing something like

import { Button } from 'my-library';

Unfortunately, it's still bundling the whole library in my app, not only the Button.

Comment: @florinpavel That's because the `index` file is just there for flexibility and to provide the whole library as a single package. Importing from that file directly implies pulling in the whole library. If you want to avoid pulling in the full library, the API consumer (assuming no use of tree-shaking) must import from the modules directly. In your example `import { Button } from 'my-library/button` which is similar to the suggestion proposed by react-bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it is all about modules and module files and their organization. You can have a lot of.. lets call them folders, "compoments/*" for example. "components/button", "components/alert", "component/badge", and other things. All of them will have some index.js or .ts file that will export or declare and export all the functionality that needed in order to make this component work, `'react-bootstrap/Button'` for example. Ideally all those subfolders or submodules are independend from each other, no references between them but probably each one will have 1 reference to 1 common/shared submodule like "components/common" which will contain some constants, for example, and no references to other files. At the top level of them you will have another index.js or .ts file that is referencing all of those components, so "components/index.js" will import and reexport all the nested components index files. So in order to import a Button, for example, you can either import "components/index.js" file with all the other imports this file is using, either only 1 single "components/button/index.js" file which is obviously much more easy to fetch. Just imagine a tree data structure, you import root of the tree (root index.js) - you get all the tree nodes. You import one specific Node (components/button/index.js) of the tree - just load all the childs (imports) of that node.

Sorry for a long read but asuming you mentioned `webpack` - there is a technique called `tree-shaking` which will cut off all the unused things.

Info about modules: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_modules.asp

Info about Tree-Shaking: https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, what you are asking is:
"How to export react components"

OR

"How are react components exported to be able to use it in a different react project ?"

Now coming to your actual question:

> import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button' instead of import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

The reason is 'Button' component is the default export of that file [react-bootstrap/Button.tsx](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/9363f656d47b701484a1f87f28bef2ee3fbe3c4a/src/Button.tsx#L109). So there is no need for destructuring a specific component.

If you export multiple components/ functions out of a file, only 1 of them can be a default export.

If you have only 1 export in a file you can make it the default export.

Consider the file project/elements.js

```
export default function Button(){
// Implementation of custom button component
}

export function Link(){
// Implementation of custom Link component
}

function Image(){
// Implementation of custom Image component
}
```

Notice that the Button component has 'default' as a keyword and the Link component doesn't.

The Image component can't even be imported and can only be used by other functions/components in the same file.

Now in project/index.js

```js
import 'Button', {Link} from './elements.js'
```

As Button component is the default export its possible to import without destructuring and as Link component is a regular export, I have to destructure it for importing.